# Update Text on Asp control using JavaScript?

Tags: asp.net, performance

I am trying to update the text on an ASP control using JavaScript. The code below seems like it should set it, but the text on the screen never actually changes. Can someone show me what is wrong with the code below?

Markup

```
<asp:Label ID="lblBlah2" CssClass="Blah" Runat="server" Text="OriginalText"></asp:Label>
```

JavaScript

```
            var t = document.getElementById('<%=lblBlah2.ClientID %>'); 
            t.attributes["Text"] = 'NewlyUpdateText'; 
            alert(t.attributes["Text"]);
```

When the JavaScript alert fires, I see "NewlyUpdateText", however, the text of the control on the screen still says "OriginalText". Why does the change in text get ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Labels are rendered as span elements in the HTML code generated but you are setting the text as an attribute. Instead, you should do this:

```
 var t = document.getElementById('<%=lblBlah2.ClientID %>'); 
 t.innerHTML = 'NewlyUpdateText';
```

Comment: thanks for the response. Does this innerHTML apply to all asp controls, or just labels? I have some other non-label asp controls I am fighting with as well.

Comment: It depends on the kind of asp.net control you are referring and how is it rendered on the page. Labels are rendered as `<span>`; GridViews as `<table>`; Hyperlink as `<a>`, and so on...

Comment: I just gave it a try and it is working like a charm. Thanks for your help.